# Prove that if $X$ is compact, then every continuous function $f: X \to Y$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness, uniform-continuity

> Prove that if $X$ is compact, then every continuous function $f: X \to Y$ is uniformly continuous.

What I did was proof by contradiction, so I assumed $f$ was not uniformly continuous. Then, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ and $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ in $X$ such that $d\bigl(f(x_n), f(y_n)\bigr) \geq \epsilon$ for all $n$, but
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n, y_n) = 0. 
$$

Since $X$ is compact, there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ that converges to some $x \in X$. Since the limit is zero, $\{y_{n_k}\}$ also converges to $x$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x$,
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = f(x) 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
\lim_{k \to \infty} f(y_{n_k}) = f(x) 
$$
which gives:
$$
d\bigl(f(x_{n_k}), f(y_{n_k})\bigr) \leq 
d\bigl(f(x_{n_k}), f(x)\bigr) + 
d\bigl(f(x), f(y_{n_k})\bigr) 
$$
which converges to $0$ as $k \to \infty$ since $f$ is continuous, which contradicts the fact that
$d\bigl(f(x_n), f(y_n)\bigr) \geq \epsilon$
for all $n$. Thus, $f$ must be uniformly continuous.

---

Is this logic right? Is it missing something?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: I edited your post to make it a bit more readable. Have a look at some of the $\LaTeX$ source (under the `Edit` button) if you like.

Answer (score 5):

Your proof looks good.

Here I will provide you with a direct proof, which may be more common in textbooks.

Given $\varepsilon>0.$ By continuity, $\exists B(p,\delta_p)\subseteq X$ such that
$$d(f(x),f(p))<\varepsilon \quad \text{ if }\quad x\in B(p,\delta_p)$$
where the notation $B(p,\delta_p)$ here means the open ball centered at $p$ with radius $\delta_p>0.$

Then we see $X\subseteq\bigcup_{p\in X} B(p,\frac12\delta_p)$. Since $X$ is compact we can write
$$X=\bigcup_{j=1}^m B(p_j,\frac12\delta_{p_j})$$

Choose $\delta=\min_{j=1,\cdots,m}\{\delta_{p_j}\}>0.$

**(edit: Should be $\delta=\min_{j=1,\cdots,m}\{\frac12\delta_{p_j}\}>0,$ see the comment below.)**

Thus for any $x,y\in X$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$, we have
$$x\in B(p_j,\frac12\delta_{p_j})\text{ for some }j$$
and
$$y\in B(x,\frac12\delta_{p_j})$$
meaning that both $x,y\in B(p_j,\frac12\delta_{p_j})$.

Hence
$$d(f(x),f(y))\leq d(f(x),f(p_j))+d(f(p_j),f(y))<2\varepsilon$$

Comment: great answer.  just a minor issue: you only have $d(x,y)<\delta \le \delta_{p_j}$, you might not have $d(x,y) < \frac12\delta_{p_j}$

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Yeah, I have to choose $\delta=\min_{j=1,\cdots,m}\{{\frac{\delta_{p_j}}{2}}\}>0.$ It is a tiny typo there, what I just did was to cover $X$ by balls with radius of $\frac{\delta_{p_j}}{2}$, and that makes more sense to choose the minimum of these radius, thank you!!